# Add additional file upload fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, bootstrap-4, upload

I am using this code to allow the user to create additional upload fields. The fields are being created and the user can select a file but it is never added to the input field. The only one that works is the first one. In firebug, I noticed there is no event listener for the additonal fields that are created.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var next = 1;
    $(".add-more").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var addto = "#field" + next;
        next = next + 1;
        var newIn = '<div id="field' + next + '" class="custom-file mt-3 mb-2"><label class="custom-file-label">NewFile ' + next + '</label><input class="custom-file-input" name="field' + next + '" type="file"><input type = "text" class="form-control mt-1 mb-1" name="field' + next + '" placeholder="Text" /></div>';
        var newInput = $(newIn);
        $(addto).after(newInput);
        $("#field" + next).attr('data-source', $(addto).attr('data-source'));
        $("#count").val(next);
    });

});
```

This is the HTML for the input that already exists and for the new put that is generated when a user clicks on the button to add new files:

```
<div id="fields">
<div id="field1" class="custom-file mt-1 mb-3">
<input class="custom-file-input" id="field-1" name="field-1" type="file">
<label class="custom-file-label">New File 1</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control mt-1 mb-1" placeholder="New File">
</div>

<div id="field2" class="custom-file mt-3 mb-2">
<label class="custom-file-label">New File 2</label>
<input class="custom-file-input" name="field2" type="file">
<input type="text" class="form-control mt-1 mb-1" name="field2" placeholder="Please provide a brief description of the uploaded file">
</div>

<button id="b1" class="btn btn-success add-more mt-4" type="button">Add more files</button>
</div>
```

Just a note; I am using Bootstrap 4.

Does anybody know the cause of this?

EDIT: I have just added this code and when I try to upload using the dynamically created inputs, the alert is 'undefined'

```
$("#fields").delegate("input[type=file]", "change", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

I have created a fiddle using the code kindly provided by Bhushan and it appears to be working just fine. I think I may have a conflict within my application.

http://jsfiddle.net/kogcyc/x1hphsvb/

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the event listener for file inputs/

Comment: I don't think I have one. I assumed because I was using Bootstrap it would be ok. Is this why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are attaching change event handler for only fields input and not to the new file input added.

please repalce

```
$("#fields").delegate("input[type=file]", "change", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

with -- here we are attaching change event handler using `.on` and selector will look for all file input having id starts with fields

```
$(document).on("change","input[id^=field][type=file]",  function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Bhushan but even though there is now an event listener, no file is uploaded. There are no errors either. I am at a bit of a loss!

Comment: are you getting file input id correctly in the alert?

Comment: also, one more thing i noticed that the actual structure have div - input - label - input but the one you are creating using add more button has div-label-input -input. does that affect bootstrap functionality?

Comment: Yes the correct ID is appearing in the input. I have checked the structure and have made sure it is now exactly the same when the buttonis clicked. For some reason though, the is no file being attached.

Comment: have you verified the console logs in the browser if any error and if you can share what bootstrap code you are using to upload files and where exactly it is failing